# Something strange with htmleditor

Tags: extjs, textarea

some problem with htmleditor

my code:

```
xtype           : 'htmleditor',
```

just simple write and i have got this :

LINK -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmUjl.png

ALL HTMLEDITOR is non-clickable. What you can advise me?

Comment: do you get any error? you need to provide more info on your issue if you need help

Comment: @Abdel, nono, i havent error, everything seems perfectly, but this htmleditor is non-clickable with no error:S:(

Comment: Have the same poblem. But only in Chrome. Works fine in IE7/8/9 and FF.It seems that its disabled all the time. Theres no errors or warnings. Any ideas?

Comment: fuh, i'm not alone with this problem. Did you tried to inlucde htmlEditor.js? I tried but what i get this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030778/strange-problem-with-textarea

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialized your quick tips? If you don't initialize you get issues with html editor buttons.

Initialize the quicktips before you create your form or best in your onReady method.

```
 Ext.QuickTips.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

This applies to ExtJS 5.1 but have not tried with other versions.

With Chrome, after you have set the value of the html editor using form.loadRecord() I found you have to explicitly call editor.setReadOnly(false); to make it editable again.

Also if you get an error e.g. **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'match' of null** then try my suggested fix here https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?264418-HtmlEditor-error-in-Chrome&p=1129716#post1129716